# Theme integrated to plugin wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, themes

i am writing a wordpress plugin and i want to make some changes on appearence of site.How can i change some html and css with my plugin?

What i mean is this:I do something with my plugin and i have some result with that.I want to add some css and make it beautiful.Where i want to make change is home screen.How can i do that?

For example,a theme's div class name is foo,another one is hoo.

Now when i want to prepend something to that div there is no similiarity.So i decided to write a little theme which is integrated to my plugin.

With another word,i want to change theme automatically by my plugin.Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can add new 'CSS' and 'Javascript' in header of you website using

```
<?php
add_action('wp_head', 'your_function');
?>
```

In that CSS file you can create whatever CSS classes you want. And yes this can be accomplished using plugin (But not recommended).

Comment: Hmm I guess you are newbie to wordpress. Actually you don't need plugin to add theme in wordpress. Why do you want to add theme using plugin?

Comment: If you want to activate theme using plugin consult this article it'll be helpful http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Template_Actions

Answer (score 0):

You will need to read a little bit about things like:

- https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin
- http://www.onextrapixel.com/2009/07/01/how-to-design-and-style-your-wordpress-plugin-admin-panel/
- http://wp.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-include-javascript-and-css-in-your-wordpress-themes-and-plugins/

Good luck and eventually let us know please :)